# Como borro un INPUT de un formulario después de procesar los datos

Tags: php

Tengo un form con un input de texto y un botón. Cuando pulsas el botón se ejecuta un php que hace una consulta a una bbdd del valor introducido. Y muestra una serie de datos en un iframe.
El caso es que cuando pulsas el botón de enviar, quiero que el input se limpie y no soy capaz. He probado mil opciones que he visto por el foro, pero ninguna me vale, o no sé aplicarla en mi código.

El html es este:

```
<html><head><meta charset="utf-8"> </head>

<body background="fondo.jpg" onload="document.getElementById('cursor').focus()">

<form name="formulario" action="consulta.php" target="ventana" id="formulario" autocomplete="off">
  <p>Codigo entrada: <input type="text" name="entrada" id="cursor"></p>
  <p><input id="barras" type="submit" value="Enviar"></p>
</form>

<iframe name="ventana" src="consulta.php">

</body>

</html>
```

Y "consulta.php" es un archivo diferente en la misma carpeta.

Conseguí que en onClick del botón me ejecutase una función Javascript para limpiarlo pero no soy capaz de ejecutar el PHP, es decir, o hago una cosa o la otra, pero combinarlas no doy con la solución.

Muchas gracias!

Comment: Te recomiendo que uses Ajax o la nueva API Fetch de Javascript para esto. Será todo más simple e incluso podrías prescindir del `iframe`, que no hace otra cosa que sobre-cargar y producir una mala experiencia de usuario.

Comment: Para que el input no se limpie entonces, el script que procesa los datos del formulario esta en la misma vista, lo que puede funcionar aqui es utilizar una variable de session que se vuelva true al enviar, y entonces con PHP hagas un echo en los valores de tu input que devuelva una cadena vacia

Answer (score 0):

te recomiendo que lo manejes de otra forma, por lo que veo intentas mandar un valor de un input y mostrar en un iframe el resultado de lo que procesas, yo haría algo así usando jquery.

Le estarìas enviando por POST al archivo consulta.php el valor del input con id cursor y lo que respondas en el php te lo traes en data y lo metes en resultado.
Incluí la llamada a jquery para poder hacer uso de ajax

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
function enviar_data(){
    $.ajax({
         url: 'consulta.php',
         type: "POST",
         data: {
            "cursor":cursor
         },
         success: function(data){
            if(data){
                $("#resultado").html(data);
            }
         }
    });
}
</script>
```

el html para esto sería algo así

```
<p>Codigo entrada: <input type="text" id="cursor"></p>
<p><button id="barras" onclick="enviar_data()">Enviar</button></p>
<div id="resultado"></div>
```

Espero haberte ayudado
Saludos

Comment: Mil gracias Lucas! Lo he implementado pero me sale un error "f1-2.html:15 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier" en esta línea "success: function(data){" no controlo nada de ajax, ¿quizá deba modificar algo del php?, ahí iba lanzando por 'echo' los mensajes que quería mostrar.

Comment: perdón me comí una coma despues del nodo data probalo y cualquier cosa me avisas. saludos

Comment: Le puse la coma pero ahora me sale otro error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object", en la llamada del ajax. No sé si tendrá que ver con el PHP que haya que cambiarle algo para recoger los datos o para mostrarlos

Comment: El còdigo que queres devolver en php devolvelo con echo, no uses return es posible que venga por ahi. Si queres pega el código completo como lo tenes y lo vemos